# Busca de maior data por um ID especifico

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, query

Estou com um problema em uma `SQL` onde necessito buscar a maior data de um `ID` especifico, onde tem vários registros deste mesmo `ID`:

Dados:

> ID - data - nome
>
> 2 - 10/10/2004 - cesar 
>  5 - 10/10/2008 - joana 
>  4 - 10/10/2002
>   - maria 
>  1 - 04/01/2017 - paulo 
>  1 - 12/12/2017 - paulo 
>  4 - 10/10/2000 - maria 
>  5 - 10/10/2017 - joana

Neste exemplo gostaria de buscar o `ID = 1` que corresponde ao nome paulo e necessito da maior data em especifico, a seguir segui minha `SQL` onde busco a maior data, mas o nome vem outro e não do `ID` referente.

```
SELECT MAX(data) as data, nome FROM teste WHERE id = '1'
```

> Resultado ... 1 - 12/12/2017 - cesar
>
> Esperado  ... 1 - 12/12/2017 - paulo

ou seja, percebi que me retorna o primeiro nome do Banco, e não é o que necessito.

Comment: tentou agrupar? algo assim: `SELECT MAX(data) as data, nome FROM teste WHERE id = 1 group by id`

Comment: sim, ae traz todos com ID 1

Comment: Faz ao contrário, primeiro vai buscar todos os registo com id = 1 e depois vê qual desses é o maior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após muita pesquisa encontrei a solução do meu problema e vou repassar a solução !!

> SELECT * FROM teste WHERE data = ( SELECT max(data) FROM teste WHERE
>   id = 1 )

Obrigado a todos pela cooperação.

Answer (score 2):

Voce pode resolver tudo com apenas uma consulta fazendo:

```
SELECT data, nome FROM teste WHERE id = '1' order by data desc limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode resolver isso fazendo primeiro a query ordenando pela data depois outra query limitando a 1.

```
CREATE TABLE `teste` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL
) 

INSERT INTO testeVALUES('2','2004-10-10','cesar'),('5','2008-10-10','joana'),
('4','2002-10-10','maria'),('1','2017-01-04','paulo'),('1','2017-12-12','paulo'),
('4','2000-10-10','maria'),('5','2017-10-10','joana');


SELECT
    aux.*
FROM(
SELECT 
    data as `data`, 
    nome 
FROM teste WHERE id = '1'
ORDER BY `data` DESC
) AS aux
LIMIT 1
;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não funfa a query: MSG mysql ( cada tabela derivada deve ter seu proprio alias  )

Comment: coloquei um alias -> as resultado ..... e exibe o mesmo resultado 1 - 12/12/2017 - cesar

Comment: Ops, desculpa, faltaram algumas coisas ali, vou editar, eu tinha deixado o MAX sem quere, ai o resultado era o mesmo.

Comment: @ThiagoLopez, se quiser testar agora!

Comment: Não houve mudança :/

Comment: Adicina um um DESC depois do ORDER BY data, ali

Comment: Nada amigo, continua retornando a data correta, porem o nome é o primeiro da tabela !!

Comment: Sinceramente, inseri os mesmos dados na tabela, que você passou, executei a query e o resultado veio correto

Comment: aqui nao ta funfando !

Comment: Na verdade, agora que reparei direito .... esta vindo o primeiro registro da taela, nem esta pegando a maior data !!

Comment: alguem ae faz um teste por favor .... não tem como uma query ter dois coportamentos em pcs diferentes.